# Facing php version related issue with magento extension

Tags: magento-1.9

I am facing an issue with `$this` in a code of extension. Looks like PHP version issue. In one server all working fine and in another server it is not working & giving error like this :-

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in filename.php on line no. 12
```

The code on line no.12 is :

```
if (!$this->getConditions())
{
    return true;
}
```

If I comment this code then error comes on another line where there is $this.

The server where everything is working fine, it's PHP version is : 5.3
The server where error is coming, it's PHP version is : 7.0

I guess this PHP version may be the issue but can anyone please tell the solution for this? or there is no way except changing the PHP version?

*EDIT*: scope:

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_SalesRule_Rule_Condition_Product_Comb‌​ine 
    extends Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Product_Combine
{
    public function validate(Varien_Object $object)
    {
        if (!$this->getConditions()) {
            return true;
        }

        // ..... other code....

    }
}
```

Comment: Is the scope of the code a static method by chance?

Comment: no not a static method. Here is the class & main function :-
class Namespace_Module_Model_SalesRule_Rule_Condition_Product_Combine extends Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Product_Combine
{
    public function validate(Varien_Object $object)
    {
     if (!$this->getConditions())
  {
      return true;
  }
  .....other code....
    }
}

Any idea?

Comment: Are you calling the method as being static from somewhere else?

Comment: Hi Giel, first of all thank you for your interest in solving this for us but the thing is wherever $this comes, error comes there except that we do not know any thing. We know only that no error coming in one server & in another server the above given error comes :(

Answer (score 1):

We came across the same issue while working a client's site. The problem for us was that the method was being *called* statically

Here's the snippet we updated

```
$valid = Mage_Rule_Model_Condition_Combine::validate($object);
```

to

```
$combiner = Mage::getModel('rule/condition_combine');
$valid = $combiner->validate($object);
```

**Note:** For our use case, we directly instantiated `Mage_Rule_Model_Condition_Combine` because we wanted to avoid using the rewrite (which was for a third party module)

Comment: I got the same issue and fixed it with suggested. Thanks